# Android Application Memory Usage with Google Maps & Memory Limits

Tags: android, google-maps, memory

I'm relatively new to programming and am building an app for practice/fun, but I'm having trouble understanding memory usage in Android (even after 12 hours of research). I've created an Android app with Google Maps, but noticed that Android Studio's memory profiler showed high memory usage (around 90-120MB total) even after force garbage collection and checking for memory leaks.

I'm pretty confused. Multiple websites state that each Android application is allocated a limited amount of memory. I've read that older devices tend to allocate 16MB, while newer devices tend to allocate 32MB (which varies depending on screen size/resolution).

- Is this memory usage problematic (around 100 MB on Android Studio's
  memory profiler)?
- Could someone explain how an application's memory
  limit (the 16/32MB limit mentioned above) relates to what is shown on
  Android's memory profiler?
- Is the limit not enforced when I run an
  app from Android Studio (perhaps b/c I'm developing)?
- Does the memory limit only apply to things that can't be garbage collected?
- Does the memory limit not apply to a Google Maps fragment (since Google runs Android)?

From what I've read, the profiler can show memory usage that is not directly related to an application, but that wouldn't seem to account for the difference between the allocate memory limit and what the profiler shows.

When I tried to find out more about where the difference was coming from, I saw that Google's open-source Santa Tracker App showed around 90MB of memory usage. I'm inclined to think that this is a normal amount of memory usage maybe since the app uses Google Maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's different pools of memory in the memory profiler-  code, java heap, etc.  The one that matters for your case is Java heap.  That's what's limited.  32 MB would be a small value for modern devices, its much closer to 100MB these days.  16 MB would be what it was back in 2011 or so.  I would be extremely surprised if any device made in the past 7 years was that low.

The limit would be enforced, but it would be enforced by whatever your simulator is set to.  Which I have no idea what it is.  It would include the Google Maps fragment, it would include all memory stored on the Java heap.